# useEffect is not getting fire on dependency change in React JS getting Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-typescript

In my react code, useEffect is not working properly. There is Modal in which I am showing some question and when i move forward to the Next que it's working fine but in case of back to 1st ques from 2nd it's not working even though state is getting change. So, I have some logic in useEffect which is not working when I wanted to move to 1st que from 2nd que, it is working fine when I move from 3rd que to 2nd que and so on, but when I wanted to moved from 2nd to 1st que then it's not working. Here is code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAppContext } from '../../hooks/AppContext';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Modal } from 'carbon-components-react';
import Step1 from '../Molecules/Steps/Step1';
import Step2 from '../Molecules/Steps/Step2';
import Step3 from '../Molecules/Steps/Step3';
import Step4 from '../Molecules/Steps/Step4';

export const PopUpModal = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  const { modal, setModal, questions, setCurrentQuestion } = useAppContext();
  const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
  console.log('modal', modal);
  const history = useHistory();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('step useeffet', step);
    if (step === 1) {
      setCurrentQuestion('Q1'); // this is working initially but moving back from 2nd to 1st not working although step is getting update.
    } else if (step === 2) {
      setCurrentQuestion('Q2');
    } else if (step === 3) {
      setCurrentQuestion('Q3');
    } else if (step === 4) {
      setCurrentQuestion('Q4');
    }
  }, [step, setStep]);
  console.log('step =>', step);

  const updateStepIndex = (index: number) => {
    if (index === 4) {
      return;
    } else {
      setStep(index);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Modal
      open={modal}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        if (step === 1) {
          setModal(false);
          history.push('/');
        } else {
          updateStepIndex(step - 1);
        }
      }}
      primaryButtonText={'Next'}
      secondaryButtonText={'Back'}
      modalHeading={'Testing Modal'}
      onRequestSubmit={() => {
        if (step < 5) {
          setStep(step + 1);
        }
      }}
      size="md"
    >
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="bx--row">
            <Step1 isOpen={step === 1 ? true : false} />
            <Step2 isOpen={step === 2 ? true : false} />
            <Step3 isOpen={step === 3 ? true : false} />
            <Step4 isOpen={step === 4 ? true : false} />
          </div>
        </div>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

This is Step1 component if u think might some issue with Step1 component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'carbon-components-react';
import { useAppContext } from '../../../hooks/AppContext';

const Step1 = ({ isOpen }: { isOpen: boolean }) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  const { getQuestion, currentQuestion } = useAppContext();
  console.log('currentQuestion', currentQuestion);
  const question = getQuestion(currentQuestion);
  console.log('question', question);
  return (
    <>
      {isOpen ? (
        <div className="modal-question">
          <h3 className="bx--type-expressive-heading-03">
            {question?.text}
          </h3>
          <Dropdown
            ariaLabel="Dropdown"
            label="Select your best match"
            titleText={''}
            items={question?.options}
            onChange={(e: any) => console.log(e)}
            initialSelectedItem={'Government'}
            light={true}
          />
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default Step1;
```

This error I am getting
**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')**

Comment: `indexOf` doesn't appear anywhere in the code. Without a complete stack trace and some way to relate it back to the code it's impossible *(or at least irritating)* to guess. If nothing else I'd make sure I'd tried to use the current state to set the next state any time I'm updating `step`.

Comment: I didn't use indexOf in any file but still I am getting this one

Comment: Please see original comment.